# Getting error using xml path and dynamic sql to generate html

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, dynamic

I'm trying to build a procedure that will take the name of a table or view and generate the html to pass to sp_db_mail.   If I manually create the query to generate the  statements it works fine but when I build the query through a cursor I get an error "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'FOR'." related to the XML Path statement.

Any thoughts on what I'm doing wrong to build the statement?

```
    DECLARE
       @wQuery AS NVARCHAR (MAX),
       @columnoutput   NVARCHAR (50)
    DECLARE @objectname AS NVARCHAR (50)
    DECLARE @body   NVARCHAR (MAX)
    DECLARE @xml   NVARCHAR (MAX)


    SET @objectname = '[dbo].[testtable]'

    DECLARE
       db_cursor CURSOR FOR SELECT CASE A.maxid - A.column_id
                                      WHEN 0
                                      THEN
                                         '[' + A.column_name + '] as ''td'''
                                      ELSE
                                           '['
                                         + A.column_name
                                         + '] as ''td'', '''','
                                   END
                                      AS columndata
                              FROM (SELECT c.name AS column_name,
                                           c.column_id,
                                           SCHEMA_NAME (t.schema_id)
                                              AS type_schema,
                                           t.name AS type_name,
                                           t.is_user_defined,
                                           t.is_assembly_type,
                                           c.max_length,
                                           c.precision,
                                           c.scale,
                                           c.object_id,
                                           (SELECT max (column_id)
                                              FROM sys.columns
                                             WHERE object_id = c.object_id)
                                              maxid
                                      FROM sys.columns AS c
                                           JOIN sys.types AS t
                                              ON c.user_type_id = t.user_type_id
                                     WHERE c.object_id = OBJECT_ID (@objectname)--ORDER BY c.column_id
                                   ) AS A

    SET @wQuery = 'CAST ((Select '

    OPEN db_cursor
    FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor   INTO @columnoutput

    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
       SET @wQuery = @wQuery + @columnoutput

       FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor   INTO @columnoutput
    END

    CLOSE db_cursor
    DEALLOCATE db_cursor


    SET @wQuery =
             @wQuery
           + ' from '
           + @objectname
           + ' FOR XML PATH ( ''tr'' ) , ELEMENTS) AS NVARCHAR (MAX)) '

    EXECUTE sp_executesql @wQuery, N'@var nvarchar(max) output', @xml OUT
```

Answer (score 0):

it seems that line

```
SET @wQuery = 'CAST ((Select '
```

should be

```
SET @wQuery = 'SELECT CAST ((Select '
```